# How Aggregate value without explode in Spark using scala language

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.2 version and Scala as a programming language.

**Input data:**

`{"amount":"2.00","cal_group":[{}],"set_id":7057}
{"amount":"1.00","cal_group":[{}],"set_id":7057}
{"amount":"7.00","cal_group": [{"abc_cd":"abc00160","abc_cnt":6.0,"cde_cnt":7.0},{"abc_cd":"abc00160","abc_cnt":5.0,"cde_cnt":2.0},{"abc_cd":"abc00249","abc_cnt":0.0,"cde_cnt":1.0}],"set_id":7057}`

**Input dataframe:**

```
[2.00,WrappedArray([null,null,null]),7057]
[1.00,WrappedArray([null,null,null]),7057]
[7.00,WrappedArray([abc00160,6.0,7.0],[abc00160,5.0,2.0,],[abc00249,0.0,1.0]),7057]
```

**Input data schema:**

```
|-- amount: string (nullable = true)
|-- cal_group: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- abc_cd: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- abc_cnt: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- cde_cnt: double (nullable = true)
|--set_id: double
```

***Note***: Each wrapped array is a struct that contains **abc_cd** and some 2 other measures columns.

I want to do two level of aggregation on input data. It is mention as Step 1 and Step 2.

**Step 1:**

We need to get the sum of amount for each **set_id** and remove nulls while doing collect_list for **cal_group**

**I have tried below code:**

```
val res1=res.groupBy($"set_id").agg(sum($"amount").as('amount_total),collect_list(struct($"cal_group")).as('finalgroup))
```

It is giving me sum **amount** as expected. 
But here I don't know how to skip null WrappedArray **cal_group** column.

**Output: step 1**

```
[7057,10.00,WrappedArray([WrappedArray([null,null,null])],[WrappedArray([null,null,null])],[WrappedArray([null,null,null])],[WrappedArray([abc00160,6.0,7.0],[abc00160,5.0,2.0],[abc00249,0.0,1.0])])
```

**Step 2:**

Then I want aggregate 2 measures(**abc_cnt, cde_cnt**) at **abc_cd** code level.

Here this aggregation can be done by explode function on cal_group column. It will convert cal_group records at row level, It will increase rows/volume of data.

So, I tried exploding the struct  and did group by on **abc_cd**.

**Sample code if use explode function to do sum:**

```
   val res2 = res1.select($"set_id",$"amount_total",explode($"cal_group").as("cal_group"))
    val res1 = res2.select($"set_id",$"amount_total",$"cal_group")
                         .groupBy($"set_id",$"cal_group.abc_cd")
                         .agg(sum($"cal_group.abc_cnt").as('abc_cnt_sum),
                              sum($"cal_group.cde_cnt").as('cde_cnt_sum),
                              )
```

***So here, I don't want to explode the col_group column.
as it is increasing the volume.***

**Output expected after Step 2:**

```
[7057,10.00,WrappedArray(**[WrappedArray([null,null,null])],
                                       [WrappedArray([null,null,null])],
                                       [WrappedArray([null,null,null])],
                                       [WrappedArray([abc00160,11.0,9.0],
                                                     [abc00249,0.0,1.0])])
```

Is there any option available, where the function should aggregate at record level and remove the null struct before collecting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could write a UDF to filter the null structs. But I doubt that'll be more efficient than explode + filter.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, It is coming null after reading. I am reading data from HDFS as parquet file.

Comment: You want to remove the abc_cd == null or all three in the struct?

Comment: I want to remove null values from struct for three.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `udf` function *for the second part aggregation* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def aggregateUdf = udf((nestedArray: Seq[Seq[Row]])=>
  nestedArray
    .flatMap(x => x
      .map(y => (y(0).asInstanceOf[String], (y(1).asInstanceOf[Double], y(2).asInstanceOf[Double]))))
      .filterNot(_._1 == null)
      .groupBy(_._1)
      .map(x => (x._1, x._2.map(_._2._1).sum, x._2.map(_._2._2).sum)).toArray
)
```

And you can call the `udf` function *after your first aggregation* (*that too need modification by removing the struct part*)

```
val finalRes=res
  .groupBy($"set_id")
  .agg(sum($"amount").as('amount_total),collect_list($"cal_group").as('finalgroup))
  .withColumn("finalgroup", aggregateUdf('finalgroup))
```

so the `finalRes` would be

```
+------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
|set_id|amount_total|finalgroup                               |
+------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
|7057  |10.0        |[[abc00249,0.0,1.0], [abc00160,11.0,9.0]]|
+------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I took below json data and loaded to get an identical schema as yours:

```
{"amount":"2.00","cal_group":[{}],"set_id":7057.0}
{"amount":"1.00","cal_group":[{}],"set_id":7057}
{"amount":"7.00","cal_group": [{"abc_cd":"abc00160","abc_cnt":6.0,"cde_cnt":7.0},{"abc_cd":"abc00160","abc_cnt":5.0,"cde_cnt":2.0},{"abc_cd":"abc00249","abc_cnt":0.0,"cde_cnt":1.0}],"set_id":7057}
```

> But here I don't know how to skip null WrappedArray cal_group column

I think `collect_list` automatically removes null, but in your case it isn't able to, since you have used a `struct` for aggregation that's not required. So, the correct transformation for **Step 1** is :

```
val res1=res.groupBy($"set_id").agg(sum($"amount").as('amount_total),(collect_list($"cal_group")).as('finalgroup))
```

which gives below output (`show` and `printSchema`)

```
+------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|set_id|amount_total|finalgroup                                                                |
+------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|7057.0|10.0        |[WrappedArray([abc00160,6.0,7.0], [abc00160,5.0,2.0], [abc00249,0.0,1.0])]|
+------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
root
 |-- set_id: double (nullable = true)
 |-- amount_total: double (nullable = true)
 |-- finalgroup: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- abc_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- abc_cnt: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- cde_cnt: double (nullable = true)
```

**Step 2**

Below assumes above code is run as Step 1. I am using explode mechanism only.

To handle your data structure, you have to do explode twice, as the structure post `amount` grouping for `cal_group` is a doubly nested array. Below is the code which gives the desired o/p:

```
val res2 = res1.select($"set_id",$"amount_total",explode($"finalgroup").as("cal_group"))
val res3 = res2.select($"set_id",$"amount_total",explode($"cal_group").as("cal_group_exp"))
val res4 = res3.groupBy($"set_id",$"cal_group_exp.abc_cd")
                          .agg(sum($"cal_group_exp.abc_cnt").as('abc_cnt_sum),
                              sum($"cal_group_exp.cde_cnt").as('cde_cnt_sum))
res4.show(false)
```

with output:

```
+------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|set_id|  abc_cd|abc_cnt_sum|cde_cnt_sum|
+------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|7057.0|abc00160|       11.0|        9.0|
|7057.0|abc00249|        0.0|        1.0|
+------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Sujit, We tried similar approach, but we had nulls within the struct in input, so its not able to remove null even if we use collect_list

Comment: I have edited my question and added input data. Your input data missing cal_group for 1st two rows.

Comment: All you need is a filter in the middle @Vijay_Shinde and you should be fine